# jQuery skip first 3 elements and the last one

Tags: jquery, element, skip

I want to use unwrap but skip from applying this to the first 3 elements and from the last one also.. How can I do this? This is what I tried:

```
$(".top_link:gt(3)").not(":last").unwrap();
```

It doesn't seem to work.. What can I do? Thank you for any idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$(".top_link:gt(2):not(:last)").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be tricky but you can always count the number of .top_link and subtract one.

```
$(".top_link:gt(3):lt("+($(".top_link").length - 1)+")").unwrap();
```